# Rigify Button when i try to generate weights it moves mesh and dispach part of it and in general doesn't work

Tags: rigify

So i am trying to follow this tutorial(i downloaded free mesh from internet that i like):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHa2Y8zjtZQ&t=9s
And as in title, when i try to generate weights to bones hips will stay in place, rest of the mesh will go down, bones will stay in place and it will generate weirdly, so it will work, but it will deform mesh quite badly. I think problem lays with how mesh is sectioned, but i don't know what to do. Here are screenshots
[image]
Before weight applying:
[image]
After weight applying:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure but I suspect it has to do with the transforms of the character/rig. They may need to be applied. If you share your file I would take a look. You can upload it here https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/aba547dbac974184a45e608b48746347
Ok so, i double checked this model, now weirdly enough applying weights work, but IK rig doesn;t move character in pose mode, if you would like to, you can check that character, maybe someone will have same problem and find solution here, i just found another model that rigify works with, and changed my character ingame for that one, but if IK gonna work on this one here, i would gladly change it back to it.Thanks for help :D

Comment: Thanks. I just checked and was able to fix it.
-The problem with parenting is that your Character objects already have some sort of parenting. Select all meshes, press Alt+P > Clear and Keep Transformations.
 -There is another problem with your meta rig. The 3 bones of the arm are: upper_arm, lower_arm, hand. Yours are aligned as shoulder, upper arm, lowe arm. This will create weird deformations.

Comment: Idk wtf i can't make your comment marked as an answer, but yes, it did work out! (i also corrected bones placement) Thanks for help, i also can't upvote your comment :V (i can only flag it) dunno why.

Comment: Ah, nice! I am glad it's solved. I posted it again as a proper reply. You should be able to mark it as solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with parenting is that your Character objects already have some sort of parenting. Select all meshes, press Alt+P > Clear and Keep Transformations. -There is another problem with your meta rig. The 3 bones of the arm are: upper_arm, lower_arm, hand. Yours are aligned as shoulder, upper arm, lower arm. This will create weird deformations.